# Wheres the best place to add non npm extensions in Reacts folder structure

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure

I'm building a React webapplication but got multiple JS and CSS extensions (Not available in the node package manager), which I want to integrate into my project.
Since I don't find it pretty to add a vendor folder into the src directory, and also the public folder doesn't seem to be the correct place, what is the best directory or most common used place to add those (as example) Iconfonts, js gallery slider etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one "right" way to structure your folders. If you don't like the sight of a vendor folder maybe consider creating a "commons" folder and store those packages there. I know it sounds like a cop-out but really just go with whatever makes most sense in your situation.